# В чём разница между кодом описанным ниже? C++ (указатели)

Tags: c++, указатели

```
void Foo(int &a){
  a++;
}
Foo(a);
```

и

```
void Foo(int *a){
  (*a)++;
}
Foo(&a);
```

Comment: В том, что: а) в первом варианте трудно передать нулевой указатель и грохнуть программу, хотя и можно; б) во втором варианте явственно видно в точке вызова, что переменная может быть изменена;

Comment: По сути никакой разницы нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом примере мы используем ссылку на переменную `a` в качестве аргумента функции `Foo`. Это означает, что функция будет работать с самой переменной `a`, а не её копией. Изменения, внесенные внутри функции, будут отражены на исходной переменной `a` после вызова функции.

Во втором примере мы используем указатель на переменную `a` в качестве аргумента функции `Foo`. Мы передаем адрес переменной `a` с помощью оператора `&`. Внутри функции мы разыменовываем указатель с помощью оператора `*` и увеличиваем значение переменной, на которую указывает указатель. Изменения также будут отражены на исходной переменной `a` после вызова функции.

Таким образом, основная разница между двумя примерами заключается в том, как мы передаем и работаем с переменной `a`. В первом случае мы передаем саму переменную, используя ссылку, а во втором случае мы передаем адрес переменной, используя указатель.